# How do I find the equation for a parabola when given 2 points and the maximum values?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics, conic-sections

I need an equation for a parabola that passes through $2$ points and has a specific maximum value. The points are $(0, 10)$ and $(7, 0)$, and the maximum is $y=45$.

---

[image]

Comment: You need more information, an extra condition, as parabolas are not necessarily axis aligned.  Probably the exercise originally stipulated that the axis of symmetry is a vertical line (parallel to the $y$-axis).

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add that, the axis of symmetry is a vertical line.

Answer (score 2):

We start with "vertex form": $y = a(x - h)^2 + k$, where the point $(h,k)$ is the vertex.  This tells us that $k = 45$, because the maximum occurs at $y = 45$.  Now, we have $$y = a(x - h)^2 + 45$$ and two additional points that the graph has to pass through: $(0,10)$ and $(7,0)$.  We can use those two points to find the two remaining parameters, $a$ and $h$:
\begin{align}
10 &= ah^{2} + 45\tag{1}\\
0 &= a(7-h)^{2} + 45.\tag{2}
\end{align}
Now, solving for $a$ in $(1)$ gives us $$a = -\frac{35}{h^{2}}.\tag{3}$$  Substituting $(3)$ into $(2)$ gives us $$0 = -\frac{35}{h^{2}}(7 - h)^{2} + 45 = -\frac{35}{h^{2}}(49 - 14h + h^{2}) + 45.\tag{4}$$  Simplifying $(4)$ gives us \begin{alignat}{2}
\frac{9}{7}h^{2} = 49 - 14h + h^{2}&\implies\frac{2}{7}h^{2}+14h - 49 &&= 0\\
&\implies2h^{2} + 98h - 343 &&= 0.\tag{5}
\end{alignat}
We can solve $(5)$ using the quadratic formula:
$$h = \frac{-98 \pm \sqrt{(98)^2+(4)(2)(343)}}{4} = \frac{1}{2}\left(-49 \pm 21\sqrt{7}\right) \approx −52.28, \ 3.28.$$  Now, because $h$ is the $x$-coordinate of the vertex, we need to take $h>0$ based on the provided graph, so we have $$h = \frac{1}{2}\left(-49 + 21\sqrt{7}\right) = \frac{7}{2}\left(3\sqrt{7} - 7\right).$$  Lastly, then, we use this value of $h$ along with $(3)$ to get $$a = -\frac{35}{h^{2}} = -\frac{35}{\left(\frac{7}{2}\left(3\sqrt{7} - 7\right)\right)^{2}} = -\frac{10}{49}\left(3\sqrt{7}+8\right).$$  Altogether, then, your equation is $$\boxed{y = -\frac{10}{49}\left(3\sqrt{7}+8\right)\left(x - \frac{7}{2}\left(3\sqrt{7} - 7\right)\right)^{2} + 45}$$ [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/hmghyf0kgu) confirms that this is correct:[image]

Comment: Sorry but I can't seem to figure out what to do to make any progress. I might be overlooking a small detail but I can't figure out what to do. Also how would another parabola be possible?

Comment: @Druby you know that the given points are in the parabola, so replace them in $y=a(x-h)^2+45$ to find $a,h$.

Comment: @manooooh I understand I need to use $y=a(x-h)^2+45$ and plug in $(0,10)$ and $(7,0)$, but I'm unsure of how to find $a$ and $h$ once I do that.

Comment: @Druby how do you know if $(1,3)$ passes through $y=x+2$? How would you solve $2x-a=1$ for $x$? If you know these answers you should know how to deal with the problem.

Comment: @Druby the two options come from whether the vertex is on the left or right of the $y$-axis.  If it were on the left of the $y$-axis (unlike your graph), then the point $(0,10)$ would be on the right side of the vertex instead of on the left of the vertex (like your graph).

Comment: Thanks for the help DNcMor and @manooooh , but unfortunately because there are two possible parabolas what I'm trying to do won't work. I think that's also why I had trouble finding out what $a$ and $h$ were.

Comment: @Druby it's definitely still possible, you just pick the one where $h>0$.

Comment: @Druby - I've edited my answer to give a complete solution.  This ended up being a bit messier than I'd originally envisioned, but still very doable.

Answer (score 0):

There are various methods for finding the equation of the parabola; the methods themselves aren't particularly difficult, but the coordinate values given in the problem make the result look "ugly".

Since **DMcMor** worked out the "vertex form" of the equation, we will develop the "standard form" here (it isn't any "prettier").  We are given the $ \ y-$intercept of the parabola, so we know that the equation has the form $ \ y \ = \ ax^2 + bx + 10 \ $ at the start, along with the fact that $  \ a < 0 \ \ $ since the parabola "opens downward".  We are further told that one of the $ \ x-$ intercepts is located at $ \ x = 7 \ \ . $

The axis of symmetry of the parabola passes through the vertex at $ \ (h \ ,  \ 45) \ \ . $  We can use a proportionality property to find this $ \ x-$coordinate.  With the vertex form of the equation expressed as $ \ y - 45 \ = \ a·(x - h)^2 \ \ , $ having the coordinates of two points on the curve, $ \ (X_1 \ , \ Y_1) \ $ and $ \ (X_2 \ , \ Y_2) \ \ , $ allows us to write
$$ \frac{|Y_2 - 45|}{|Y_1 - 45|} \ = \ \frac{|a|·(X_2 - h)^2}{|a|·(X_1 - h)^2}  \ = \ \frac{ (X_2 - h)^2}{ (X_1 - h)^2}  \ \ . $$
For the two known points on the parabola, we can determine
$$ \frac{|10 - 45|}{|0 - 45|} \ = \ \frac{35}{45} \ = \ \frac{7}{9} \ = \  \frac{ (0 - h)^2}{ (7 - h)^2}  \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ \frac{ h}{  7 - h } \ \ = \ \ \pm \frac{\sqrt7}{3} \ \ ; $$
since the vertical distance of $ \ (0 \ , \ 10) \ $ from the vertex is smaller than for $ \ (7 \ , \ 0) \ \ , $ the vertex is a smaller *horizontal* distance from $ \ (0 \ , \ 10) \ \ , $ so we have
$$ h  \ \ = \ \ \frac{\sqrt7}{3} · ( 7 - h ) \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ \left(\frac{3 \ + \ \sqrt7}{3} \right)·h  \ \ = \ \ \frac{7\sqrt7}{3} $$ $$ \Rightarrow \ \ h  \ \ = \ \ \frac{7\sqrt7}{3  +  \sqrt7} \ \ = \ \ \frac{7\sqrt7·(3  -  \sqrt7)}{2} \ \ \approx \ \ 3.280 \ \ . $$

The axis of symmetry is midway between the $ \ x-$intercepts of a parabola, so we can calculate the second intercept as
$$ h \ = \ \frac{\mathcal{X} \ + \ 7}{2} \ \ = \ \ \frac{7\sqrt7·(3  -  \sqrt7)}{2} $$ $$ \Rightarrow \ \ \mathcal{X} \ \ = \ \ 2h  -  7 \ \ = \ \  7·(3\sqrt7  -  7) \ - \ 7·1 \ \ = \ \ 7·(3\sqrt7  -  8) \ \ \approx \ \ -0.439 \ \ . $$

Now that we know the zeroes of the quadratic polynomial (the $ \ x-$intercepts of the parabola), we can write the "factored form"  $ \ y \ = \ a·(x - 7)·( \ x \ - \ [7·(3\sqrt7  -  8)] \ ) \ \ . $  For $ \ x = 0 \ \ , $ this must give us the $ \ y-$coordinate of the $ \ y-$intercept, thus
$$ a·(0 - 7)·( \ 0 \ - \ [7·(3\sqrt7  -  8)] \ ) \ \ = \ \ 10 $$ $$ \Rightarrow \ \ a \ \ = \ \ \frac{10}{49·(3\sqrt7  -  8)} \ \ = \ \ \frac{10·(3\sqrt7  +  8)}{49·([3\sqrt7]^2  -  8^2)} \ \ = \ \ \frac{10·(3\sqrt7  +  8)}{49·(63  -  64)} $$ $$ = \ \ -\frac{10·(3\sqrt7  +  8)}{49} \ \ \approx \ \ -3.253 \ \ . $$

The middle coefficient $ \ b \ $ of the standard form can be found now by multiplying out the factored form, or by using the relation for the vertex $ \ h \ = \ -\frac{b}{2a} \ \ , $ from which we obtain
$$ b \ \ = \  \ -2·a·h \ \ = \ \  -2·\left(-\frac{10·[3\sqrt7  +  8]}{49} \right)·\left(\frac{7\sqrt7·(3  -  \sqrt7)}{2} \right) $$ $$ = \ \  \frac{10· \sqrt7}{7} · (3\sqrt7  +  8) · (3  -  \sqrt7) \ \ = \ \ \frac{10· (7 + 3\sqrt7)}{7} \ \ \approx \ \ 21.339 \ \ . $$

The standard form of the parabolic equation is therefore
$$ y \ \ = \ \ \left(-\frac{10·(3\sqrt7  +  8)}{49} \right)·x^2 \ + \ \left(\frac{10· (7 + 3\sqrt7)}{7} \right)·x \ + \ 10   $$
$$ \approx \ \ -3.253·x^2 \ + \ 21.339·x \ + \ 10 \ \ . $$
(Told you it wouldn't be pretty...)

Inserting $ \ x  =  h \ $ and $ \ x = 7 \ $ produces the given $ \ y-$coordinates of $ \ 45 \ $ and $ \ 0 \ \ , $ respectively.